# Has anyone tried putting the Powered Up system in the Christmas train?

Tags: trains, powered-up

Just wondering if anyone has taken the [powered-up](/questions/tagged/powered-up) ("Power Functions 2.0") Bluetooth system out of the Cargo Train 60198 or Passenger Train 60197 sets and put it in the Winter Holiday Train set 10254?

Comment: I going to do it next week. It looks like putting the train motor under the tender instead of the engine will be a cleaner build.

Comment: So are you pretty certain that it can be done?
I was considering buying both the Holiday train set and the Cargo train, and using the BT motor setup in the Christmas train.
But, I don't have any experience with Lego trains yet, so I wasn't sure if it would work.

Comment: The Lego instructions are good, but I am not satisfied. If I can come up with something better I will post some photos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Haven't done the 10254 yet with powered up, but have converted several other trains... The train motors have the exact same dimensions and the powered-up smart hub has the same dimensions as the battery box of the power functions system.
What's different is that you don't need the space for the IR receiver and that the motor is immediately connected to the hub rather than the receiver.

What will differ is the following steps from the instruction manual:
[image: IR-room]
Those steps make room for the IR-receiver which isn't necessary now..., for the rest you can follow the instructions exactly...

Comment: The motor is basically the identical shape and the battery box is the same size/shape, but there is one difference which could be important, which is the plug location. It's on top of the old battery box, in the middle, and on the front of the new one (and there are two, side-by-side).

Comment: Good point in general, however for the 10254, the plug location isn't a problem, the entire top and side is exposed in the tender

Comment: I did this successfully, but the train runs in reverse. i.e. the forward direction of the power function motor is toward where the wire comes from, and I presume that's the opposite from the suggested motor. I suppose there's no solution to that though?

Comment: There's a little switch on the remote that allows you to revert direction...

Comment: Thanks, not quite but I figured it out. This is the Bluetooth controller and you can rotate each individual control so "-" is at the top. It's not obvious it rotates though!